# Laravel 5 read Json file give error `Response.php line 403`

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I want to read `json` file from database directory, but give `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.` error. Bellow is my code :

```
  $json = file_get_contents('database/query_templates/course.json');
  $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);              

  echo '<pre/>'; print_r($data); exit;
```

`course.json` file content :

```
{
  "post_filter" : {
     "operator" : [
        {
           "operator" : [
              {
                "range" : {
                    "created_at" : {
                        "gte" : "log_start_date",
                        "lte" : "log_end_date",
                        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "terms" : {
                    "search_param_user_action.id" : "user_select_array"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "operator" : [
            {
                "operator" : [
                    "conduct_days_multi"
                ]
            },
            {
                "operator" : [
                    "dropdowns"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "query" : {
            "multi_match" : {
                "query" : "x",
                "fields" : [
                    "resource_search_columns"
                ],

                "operator" : "operator"
            }
         }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

for any help thanks.

Comment: What is the content of your `course.json`? Also which line is giving that error?

Comment: @MarkDavison Now I have updated question.

Comment: Where are you running this code within your Laravel project?

Comment: @MarkDavidson Yeah. Inside controller file

Comment: i suspect it's a path issue. first of all, try to dump your `$json`.

Comment: it could because of spaces could you try

 {"post_filter":{"operator":[{"operator":[{"range":{"created_at":{"gte":"log_start_date","lte":"log_end_date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd"}}},{"terms":{"search_param_user_action.id":"user_select_array"}}]},{"operator":[{"operator":["conduct_days_multi"]},{"operator":["dropdowns"]}]},{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"x","fields":["resource_search_columns"],"operator":"operator"}}}]}}

Comment: @Tezla You are right! It has path problem, when I dumped the filed in storage location it is working. But why in database directory  has problem?

Comment: well, as far as i know laravel pretty strict in file access. notice the Storage api actually won't let us do anything outside storage directory? `file_get_contents` however, isn't a laravel function, it is perhaps caused by the location of the actual executing code (the one that invokes the controller) - which this fact complicates the path. so, i don't recommend directly accessing file through plain php functions (use the laravel one). anyway, hope someone else shed more light on this - i always stick on laravel api if i code using laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some php releasees not supported get_file_contents() or this func return type string but not only return string everytime, sometimes return boolean value bacause it's working on the byte codes, you can try traditional file operation methods or you can try convert to string.